# How to map a 4 loops schema to a 3 loops schema in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-mapper

Now I have a source schema which having 3 loops, "OrderHeader", "OrderLine" and "OrderSchedule", like the following picture.

**Source schema**

[image]

Now I want to map it to the standard X12 EDI 855 schema
And the following picture is mapping

[image]

The following is my input file

```xml
  <OrderHeader>
    <code_BAK02>1</code_BAK02>
    <po_no_BAK03>2</po_no_BAK03>
    <po_date_BAK04>20200630</po_date_BAK04>
    <OrderLine>
      <assigned_id_PO101>1</assigned_id_PO101>
      <qty_PO102>1</qty_PO102>
      <OrderSchedule>
        <sch_qty_ACK02>1</sch_qty_ACK02>
      </OrderSchedule>
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderHeader>
  <OrderHeader>
    <code_BAK02>2</code_BAK02>
    <po_no_BAK03>3</po_no_BAK03>
    <po_date_BAK04>20200830</po_date_BAK04>
    <OrderLine>
      <assigned_id_PO101>1</assigned_id_PO101>
      <qty_PO102>100</qty_PO102>
      <OrderSchedule>
        <sch_qty_ACK02>100</sch_qty_ACK02>
      </OrderSchedule>
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderHeader>
```

After executing test mapping, the result is like following, which is not what I expect.

```xml
<ns0:X12_00403_855>
  <ns0:BAK>
    <BAK02>112220000204853</BAK02>
    <BAK03>20201116</BAK03>
    <BAK04>20210730</BAK04>
  </ns0:BAK>
  <ns0:BAK>
    <BAK02>112220000206821</BAK02>
    <BAK03>20201119</BAK03>
    <BAK04>20210630</BAK04>
  </ns0:BAK>
  <ns0:PO1Loop1>
    <ns0:PO1>
      <PO101>1</PO101>
      <PO102>1</PO102>
    </ns0:PO1>
    <ns0:PO1>
      <PO101>1</PO101>
      <PO102>100</PO102>
    </ns0:PO1>
    <ns0:ACKLoop1>
      <ns0:ACK>
        <ACK02>1</ACK02>
      </ns0:ACK>
      <ns0:ACK>
        <ACK02>100</ACK02>
      </ns0:ACK>
    </ns0:ACKLoop1>
  </ns0:PO1Loop1>
</ns0:X12_00403_855>
```

What I expect is like following,

```xml
<ns0:X12_00403_855>
  <ns0:BAK>
    <BAK02>112220000204853</BAK02>
    <BAK03>20201116</BAK03>
    <BAK04>20210730</BAK04>
    <ns0:PO1Loop1>
      <ns0:PO1>
        <PO101>1</PO101>
        <PO102>1</PO102>
      </ns0:PO1>
      <ns0:ACKLoop1>
        <ns0:ACK>
          <ACK02>1</ACK02>
        </ns0:ACK>
      </ns0:ACKLoop1>
    </ns0:PO1Loop1>
  </ns0:BAK>
  <ns0:BAK>
    <BAK02>112220000206821</BAK02>
    <BAK03>20201119</BAK03>
    <BAK04>20210630</BAK04>
    <ns0:PO1Loop1>
      <ns0:PO1>
        <PO101>1</PO101>
        <PO102>100</PO102>
      </ns0:PO1>
      <ns0:ACKLoop1>
        <ns0:ACK>
          <ACK02>100</ACK02>
        </ns0:ACK>
      </ns0:ACKLoop1>
    </ns0:PO1Loop1>
  </ns0:BAK>
</ns0:X12_00403_855>
```

The result I want is to following the structure of the input file, is there any method to achieve that?

Comment: The result you expect doesn't match your output schema; `PO1Loop1` isn't nested within `BAK`. Step one is debatching your input file, because now multiple orders from your input file are mapped to a single order confirmation.

Comment: Is there any methods (like using functoid) to let PO1Loop1 into BAK? I've ever tried "looping", "table looping" and "table extractor", but it still didn't work :(

Comment: While possible, it kind of defeats the purpose of using a target schema. BizTalk won't be able to process it any-way. Either map every `<OrderHeader>` from your input file separately, or use the X12_BatchSchema.xsd as a base for your output if you really want to map multiple orders at once. I recommend the former option, and, if needed, use BizTalk's built-in batching functionality to "re-batch" the messages.

Comment: OK, i got it. I'll try, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Looping is always very problematic with the visual mapper. Right click on the schema and choose 'validate schema'. It will show you the xslt it generates and can help you understand what's happening